# C++ Check HTML checkbox

Tags: c++, checkbox, mfc

I'm trying to use an web browser object in MFC to interact with a website and check a checkbox.

I have a function that gets the DOM object and then where I'm struggling is using the interface to select the checkbox.  I've been able to interact with textfields and buttons no issue. Just the checkbox that's killing me.
My elementFromID function basically does this

```
pDisp->QueryInterface(nTypeIID, (void**)&pElement);
```

Where nTypeIID is IID_IHTMLElement or whatever 2nd param is passed in.
pElement is what is returnedback.

So getting the element isn't the issue, it's interacting with it. 
No where in the MSDN documentation can I find where it says how to set a checkbox value.

```
void* pElem = ElementFromID(L"checkbox_id", IID_IHTMLElement);
if (pElem != nullptr)
{
    IHTMLElement* pCheckbox = (IHTMLElement*)pElem;
    VARIANT checked;
    checked.boolVal = true;
    checked.vt = VT_BOOL;
    pCheckbox->setAttribute(L"checked", checked, FALSE);

    // Alternate approaches that failed
    /*pElem = ElementFromID(L"order_terms", IID_IHTMLInputElement);
    IHTMLInputElement* pCheckbox = (IHTMLInputElement*)pElem;
    pCheckbox->put_checked(VARIANT_TRUE);
    pCheckbox->put_defaultChecked(VARIANT_TRUE);*/
}
```

Comment: I tested `pCheckbox->setAttribute` with `CHtmlEditCtrl`, it works fine. Your `pElem` could be wrong. Show all the relevant code which you skipped.

Comment: Yeah I'm thinking the site is doing something with javascript to make it more difficult rather than just checking the checkbox itself.

Comment: It sounds like you need UI Automation for this job. Also change the string to `CComBSTR(L"checked")`, that should work for a simple web page.

Comment: Would UI Automation work in an embedded browser? I've been looking into it since you mentioned it and it seems it would only work for applications and their elements rather than the elements within an element.

Comment: I haven't tried it but it should be possible to use UIA in that way. Try one more thing: Use `get_innerText(BSTR &text)` to see if you can get the checkbox content.